# Spring-Boot OpenAPI - @RestControllerAdvice not limited to methods throwing the Exception

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc

I need to document my SpringBoot APIs and their possible exceptions with OpenAPI,
and I am using **SpringDoc-OpenAPI** https://springdoc.org/.

To handle the **NotFound** cases I created this exception class:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

public class NotFoundException extends ResponseStatusException {
    public NotFoundException() {
        super(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

and this @RestControllerAdvice

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFoundException(RuntimeException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the generated OpenAPI yaml file has

```
  responses:
    "404":
      description: Not Found
      content:
        '*/*':
          schema:
            type: string
```

for all `@RestController` endpoints, instead of only for the methods with `throws NotFoundException`.

How can I limit the @ControllerAdvice (or the OpenAPI), to generate the 404 Response documentation only for methods with the throwing signature?

Do I need to use something else other than the @RestControllerAdvice?
I would like to avoid having to annotate every single method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to:

1. Make the `@RestControllerAdvice` `@Hidden`
2. Provide an `OperationCustomizer` `@Bean`

---

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden;
import it.eng.cysec.ot.risk.assessment.api.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@Hidden
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

---

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.MediaType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponses;
import it.eng.cysec.ot.risk.assessment.api.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OperationCustomizer;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class OperationResponseCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {
    public static final ApiResponse NOT_FOUND_API_RESPONSE;


    static {
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
        mediaType.setSchema(new StringSchema());

        Content content = new Content();
        content.addMediaType("*/*", mediaType);

        NOT_FOUND_API_RESPONSE = new ApiResponse()
                .description("Not Found")
                .content(content);
    }

    /**
     * Customize operation.
     *
     * @param operation     input operation
     * @param handlerMethod original handler method
     * @return customized operation
     */
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
        List<Class<?>> exceptions = Arrays.asList(method.getExceptionTypes());

        if(exceptions.contains(NotFoundException.class)){
            ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();
            apiResponses.addApiResponse("404", NOT_FOUND_API_RESPONSE);
        }

        return operation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on 1Z10's answer, I built a solution for Spring 6 that does what you are asking for.

I added the `@Hidden` annotation to my `RestControllerAdvice` class, and then implemented the following `OperationCustomizer` which automatically scans the method declarations in my controllers for throw clauses and adds corresponding ApiResponses for the exceptions that inherit from `ErrorResponseException` (responses with a ProblemDetail body) and are annotated with `ResponseStatus`:

```
@Component
public class OperationResponseCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {

    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
        List<Class<?>> exceptions = Arrays.asList(method.getExceptionTypes());

        ApiResponses apiResponses = operation.getResponses();

        Map<String, List<ResponseStatus>> responseCodeToAnnotations = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Class<?> exception : exceptions) {
            if (!ErrorResponseException.class.isAssignableFrom(exception)) {
                continue;
            }
            for (Annotation annotation : exception.getAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation.annotationType().equals(ResponseStatus.class)) {
                    ResponseStatus responseStatus = exception.getAnnotation(ResponseStatus.class);

                    String responseCode = responseStatus.value().value() + "";
                    responseCodeToAnnotations.putIfAbsent(responseCode,
                            new ArrayList<>());
                    responseCodeToAnnotations.get(responseCode).add(responseStatus);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        responseCodeToAnnotations.forEach((responseCode, responseStatuses) -> {
            if (responseStatuses.isEmpty())
                return;

            // generate a joined reason per responseCode
            String joinedReason = null;
            if (responseStatuses.size() > 1) {
                joinedReason = responseStatuses.stream()
                        .map(s -> String.format("- %s", s.reason()))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            } else {
                joinedReason = responseStatuses.get(0).reason();
            }

            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
            ResolvedSchema resolvedSchema = ModelConverters.getInstance().readAllAsResolvedSchema(new AnnotatedType().type(ProblemDetail.class));
            if (resolvedSchema != null) {
                Schema schema = resolvedSchema.schema;
                schema.setTitle("ProblemDetail");
                mediaType.setSchema(schema);
            }

            Content content = new Content();
            content.addMediaType("*/*", mediaType);

            ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse()
                    .description(joinedReason)
                    .content(content);

            apiResponses.addApiResponse(responseCode,
                    apiResponse);
        });

        return operation;
    }
}
```

An example exception that is picked up:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = StartTimeInPastException.REASON)
public class StartTimeInPastException extends ResponseStatusException {
    static final String REASON = "startTimeEpoch cannot lie in the past";
    public StartTimeInPastException() {
        super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, REASON);
    }
}
```

The filtering of ErrorResponseExceptions could be removed, but I suppose that then the schema of the ApiResponses has to be handled in some other way.